# Find and delete files starting or ending with certain sign

Tags: find

Using `find`, I need to find and delete files that start or end with `#` and files that end with`~` but I can't find any way. I tried:

```
find-name "#*#" -type f -delete
```

But couldn't make it fully match the patterns I want.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, the key thing that you need to know to solve that question is sort of a hidden feature for new users reading [`man find`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/find.1.html) ... That feature is you can actually specify more than one `-name "..."` pattern if the extra patterns are added with `-o -name "..." -o -name "..." ...` ... Knowing that, you can now use it e.g. like so:

```
find -type f -name "*#" -o -name "#*" -o -name "*~" -delete
```